# Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sdd1

Tags: automount

I have tried a bunch of things and I can not get a working result from the googling I have tried.
I have 3 external ext4 Hard Drives that I would like to automount containing data for Plex. I am running Ubuntu 16.04.
I keep getting this error on one or more of the drives

Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sdd1: Command-line `mount "/mnt/2tbDVR"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: /dev/sdd1 is already mounted or /mnt/2tbDVR busy
       /dev/sdd1 is already mounted on /mnt/2tbDVR

Please help.

edit: I get this error as soon as I boot, as if it is trying to mount twice.
here is my fstab, its a bit of a mess cause Im trying different things to see what works on different drives.
your opinions on fstab entries would help me too.

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=f645f3e0-fe35-4a8e-b945-6404cd3ca9dd /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=24c4fa28-3da3-471e-92b4-50bbe9784fd7 none            swap    sw              0       0

/dev/disk/by-label/PISERVER /mnt/PISERVER auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0

/dev/disk/by-label/WD40 /mnt/WD40 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0

LABEL=2tbDVR /mnt/2tbDVR auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Edit: so I went through the kernal logs and found that the drive is mounted once here 

EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)

and then again 10 lines later here 

EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro

how do I work out what is calling the mounts?

Comment: "/dev/sdd1 is already mounted on /mnt/2tbDVR" looks as if it is already mounted .

Comment: The message says that there is already a mount on `/mnt/2tbDVR`. Why then should it be mounted again? Please add the content of `/etc/fstab` to your question.

Comment: The filesystem is mounted at boot time by `systemd` (first time), but in some script(?)  run at boot time there is also an explicit `mount` command (second try). Find out where this command comes from (look in the logfiles).

Comment: Thanks ridgy. what excatly am I looking for? and which log?

Comment: What command or log can I use to find out what is mounting drives And when?